# How to create block in magento and return output to template file

Tags: magento-1.8

I need to create a block for product filtering...on base of category id....
But i dont,t know how to return block code to html template ....

I just want to know that what is the best way to create ...block and return that output to html template..

```
my block code is 

protected function getLoadedProductCollection() {


        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $products->joinField(
                'qty', 'cataloginventory/stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.stock_id=1', 'left'
        );
        $products->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('neq' => 0));
        $products->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'simple');
        $products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
        $products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
        $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        $products->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id=entity_id', null, 'left'
        );
        $products->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array(7)));

        $this->setProductCollection($products);

        return $products;


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking about it in slightly the wrong way.  The way blocks work is that a block class is instantiated and then the associated template file (assuming there is one, there doesn't have to be) is included by the block class.  This is how within template files you can use `$this` to run block class methods.  This process happens automatically when you create a block and assign a template to it whether that is via layout XML or by accessing the layout object and creating a block that way in some class.

So it's not that you return block content to the template, you call block methods from within the template and render the results however you need to.

Answer (score 1):

In etc/config.xml of your module, define layout update file like

```
<blocks>
    <(modulename)>
        <class>(ClassName_Prefix)</class>
    </(modulename)>
</blocks>
<frontend>
     <!---- other settings-->
     <layout>
        <updates>
            <(modulename)>
                <file>(name_of_layout_file.xml)</file>
            </(modulename)>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Now in your name_of_layout_file.xml in app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/name_of_layout_file.xml define phtml file path like this :

```
<block type="modulename/ClassName_Prefix" name="anything" template="modulename/className_prefix.phtml"/">
```

Now in modulename/className_prefix.phtml, you can simply call your function as $this->getLoadedProductCollection();

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Magento Design Terminologies](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/magento-design-terminologies4)

**Blocks** are a way by which Magento distinguishes the array of functionalities in the system and creates a modular way to manage it from both visual and functional stand point. There are two types of blocks and they work together to create the visual output.

- *Structural Blocks*
  These are blocks created for the sole purpose of assigning visual structure to a store page such as header, left column, main column and footer (Diagram 1).
- *Content Blocks*
  These are blocks that produce the actual content inside each structural block. They are representations of each feature functionality in a page and employs template files to generate (X)HTML to be inserted into its parent structural block. Category list, mini cart, product tags and product listingâ€¦etc are each its own content block (Diagram 2).

**Templates** (located in app/design/frontend/your_interface/your_theme/template/)
These are PHTML files that contain (X)HTML markups and any necessary PHP tags to create logic for visual presentation.

Eg

app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    .....
    /**
     * Retrieve current product model
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        if (!Mage::registry('product') && $this->getProductId()) {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId());
            Mage::register('product', $product);
        }
        return Mage::registry('product');
    }
    ...
```

/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    .....
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
            ....
```

Now you access method getProduct() within your phtml

/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
....
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
```